# how to handle floating point with openmp parallel for properly

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, floating-point, openmp

After hours of debugging and small scale example in attempts to find what I was doing wrong, I finally got one of my theory confirmed.
floating point rounding-off error.
[floating point calculations are non-associative in computers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

what can be done to reduce the errors ?

code :

```
                        double energy = 0;
                        double contrast = 0;
                        double homogeneity = 0;
                        double entropy = 0;
                        double correlation = 0;
                        double shade = 0;
                        double prominence = 0;
                        double glcmMean = 0;
                        double sigma = 0;
                        double squaredVarianceIntensity = 0;
                        double A = 0;
                        double B = 0;
                        
                        for(int c = 0; c <normalizedGlcm.cols; c++){
                            #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:homogeneity,energy,contrast,entropy,glcmMean)
                            for(int r = 0; r<normalizedGlcm.rows; r++){

                                double pij = normalizedGlcm.at<double>(r,c,0);
                                double intensity = (double)img.at<uchar>(col,row,0);

                                if(pij != 0){
                                    homogeneity += pij/(1.0+((c-r)*(c-r)));
                                    energy += pij * pij;
                                    contrast += (c-r)*(c-r)*pij;
                                    entropy += -(log(pij)*pij); // pij will never be under 0
                                    glcmMean += pij * intensity;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

after that bit there's more loops and some other calculations with the glcmMean variable. And so far I only get error with the glcmMean variable.
error examples :

```
serial     -      parrallel
1.66905e+28 vs 1.55964e+30
4.09033e+28 vs 3.62704e+30
8.38877e+30 vs 3.35551e+31
```

Comment: You can try Kahan Summation to check if the serial version has the error.

Comment: I had a whole university course dedicated to this topic and it is usually not trivial.  Look for information on : Minimize errors in numerical methods or something similar. 
If I remember correctly one of the heuristics is try to avoid divisions with small number (better calculate the inverse first) and I though log is pretty unstable as well so try to move it out of the loop. But I apologize I don't have anything really concrete to add at the moment.

Comment: `pij != 0` is unsafe because you can almost never ensure that a double FP value is 0 unless you operate on small integers. Consider using `abs(pij) < epsilon`. Note that such problem is typically due to a numerical instability and, as PepijnKramer pointed out, this is sometimes very hard to fix. Alternatively, it can be due to a race condition but your code seems fine to me.

Comment: If you are lucky, the problem is due to an accumulation of small values causing a huge relative error and the provided result due to a FP precision saturation. Using wide precision like 256-bit FP numbers often help to track such an issue (both parallel and sequential codes). If you are unlucky it can be due to the algorithm (generally a catastrophic cancellation or a threshold issue). I guess this is the first one because the parallel implementation enable to reduce this effect causing bigger numbers which is what we see.

Comment: @PepijnKramer so far I only get error with the glcmMean variable . no problem with the log which is where i would expect errors aswell.
division are handle with is_inf() later.
thats the error i need to reduce : glcmMean += pij * intensity;
pij is between -1 and 1 and intensity 0 to 255

Comment: @JérômeRichard iam pretty sure i can cast a 8bit int of value zero into a double and it will still be zero, but iam willing to learn if that is not always true.
i like the idea of trying the 256-bit FP numbers.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark no its not a typo... otherwise i would not be able to run the program and show example of the calculation errors iam getting.
the algo is looping in two different thing: the outer loop (the one you dont see in the sample) is an image and the loop you can see is a matrix calculated from a window of the image

Comment: *the outer loop (the one you dont see in the sample)* well, that's obviously where the problem is!

Comment: If both `pij` and `intensity` are integers, you can get rid off rounding errors by using a library capable to store such large integers, e.g. [check this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Comment: There is a contradiction here: you claim that `glcmMean` is about 1E30, and `pij * intensity` is between -255 - 255. It means that there is a 27 order of magnitude difference, but 1) `double` has only 15-18 significant digits, so you cannot reach such a big number by adding numbers less than 255 and ii) doing 1E27 additions are impossible. So. I agree with @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: @Laci my mistake pij goes from 0 to 1 and intensity from 0 to 255 ...
although you are right 255 * 255 * 255 should be the max value of glcmMean.

and i doubled check the min and max value of both matrix using 
cv::minMaxIdx(normalizedGlcm, &min, &max);

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the comments, you can simply try the following code that accumulate the `glcmMean` so the accumulated value are more on the same order of magnitude than in the initial code. This assume `normalizedGlcm.cols` and `normalizedGlcm.rows` are relatively close (eg. not 2 and 2000 for example).

```cpp
double energy = 0;
double contrast = 0;
double homogeneity = 0;
double entropy = 0;
double correlation = 0;
double shade = 0;
double prominence = 0;
double glcmMean = 0;
double sigma = 0;
double squaredVarianceIntensity = 0;
double A = 0;
double B = 0;

for(int c = 0; c <normalizedGlcm.cols; c++){
    double local_homogeneity = 0;
    double local_energy = 0;
    double local_contrast = 0;
    double local_entropy = 0;
    double local_glcmMean = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:local_homogeneity,local_energy,local_contrast,local_entropy,local_glcmMean)
    for(int r = 0; r<normalizedGlcm.rows; r++){
        double pij = normalizedGlcm.at<double>(r,c,0);
        double intensity = (double)img.at<uchar>(col,row,0);

        if(pij != 0){
            local_homogeneity += pij/(1.0+((c-r)*(c-r)));
            local_energy += pij * pij;
            local_contrast += (c-r)*(c-r)*pij;
            local_entropy += -(log(pij)*pij); // pij will never be under 0
            local_glcmLocalMean += pij * intensity;
        }
    }

    homogeneity += local_homogeneity;
    energy += local_energy;
    contrast += local_contrast;
    entropy += local_entropy;
    glcmMean += local_glcmMean;
}
```

If the problem was due to the FP saturation / imprecision, then it should strongly improve the accuracy of the result, especially in sequential.